# Accidentally delete /usr/bin/git file and now I cannot work with git on the terminal

Tags: xcode, macos, git

I had a problem with git on my machine and I accidentally deleted the /usr/bin/git from my system.

My git was installed through the XCode Command Line Tools and I cannot find a way to reinstall it.

The git was not uninstalled, the git file was removed.

Is there a way from XCode or somewhere else to reinstall the command line tools? or somewhere Where I can get the original git file to add to /usr/bin again?

THanks

Comment: Go to Apple developer's download site (https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) and redownload the Command Line Tools package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo cp /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git
```

I don't know why `/usr/bin/git` isn't just a symlink to that file, but on my system it's a separate (identical) copy.